# change multiple file name with script and use the previous names

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to change multiple file names with their previous names using a script, for example change file names as below:

```
2015-08-25___LSA_SP_E_txt ---> 20150825.IT.SPE.LSA.txt 
2015-08-25___HSB_BH_Z_txt ---> 20150825.IT.BHZ.HSB.txt 
2015-08-25___TEH_SP_N_txt ---> 20150825.IT.SPN.TEH.txt 
2015-08-25___ANJ_BH_E_txt ---> 20150825.IT.BHE.ANJ.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `rename`:

```bsh
rename -n 's/-//g;s/___(\w*)_(\w*)_(\w*)_/.IT.$2$3.$1./' *
```

In `-n`ono mode this only prints the changes, remove this flag to perform the renaming. The first expression just removes every hyphen, the second one saves the strings and replaces the underscore part.

An alternative is to save just *everything* you need in groups, this way you can also quickly change e.g. the date:

```
rename -n 's/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)___(\w*)_(\w*)_(\w*)_/$1$2$3.IT.$5$6.$4./' *
```

#### Example run

```
$ rename -n 's/-//g;s/___(\w*)_(\w*)_(\w*)_/.IT.$2$3.$1./' *
rename(2015-08-25___ANJ_BH_E_txt, 20150825.IT.BHE.ANJ.txt)
rename(2015-08-25___HSB_BH_Z_txt, 20150825.IT.BHZ.HSB.txt)
rename(2015-08-25___LSA_SP_E_txt, 20150825.IT.SPE.LSA.txt)
rename(2015-08-25___TEH_SP_N_txt, 20150825.IT.SPN.TEH.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash script(script.sh) to rename multiple files.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="$1"
IFS=,
[ ! -f "$INPUT" ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read old_name new_name
do
rename "$old_name" "$new_name" # mv or rename
done < "$INPUT"
```

Input.txt file format:

```
old_name1.txt,new_name1.txt
old_name2.txt,new_name2.txt
```

Use:

```
bash script.sh input.txt
```